# What is the condition for hermitian matrix $H$ to satisfy $e^{iHt}\mathbf{e_k} \cdot \mathbf{e_k} \neq 0$?

Tags: linear-algebra

What is the condition for hermitian matrix $H$ to satisfy $(e^{iHt}\mathbf{e_k}) \cdot \mathbf{e_k} \neq 0$, where $\mathbf{e_k}$ is the $k$th unit vector and $t>0$ is referring to any real number? $k$ is assumed to be given, and thus $H$ does not have to satisfy $(e^{iHt}\mathbf{e_k}) \cdot \mathbf{e_k} \neq 0$ for every $k$ (the condition only needs to be satisfied for the given $k$)

Comment: It is always true.

Comment: To see this, note that since $H$ is Hermitian, it is diagonalizable, so in the basis of eigenvectors you are just doing $\exp(i \lambda t)$ on the eigenvalues.